# INSERT to a table using SELECT and VALUES at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

how can I insert to a table using values in different way? preferably no temp table. below is my stored procedure code, but i get errors on insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setBARS
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@BUSINESSAREANAME nvarchar(50),
@STAFFNAME nvarchar(50),
@ROLENAME nvarchar(50),
@BARSSTARTDATE date,
@BARSENDDATE date
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
WITH t1 (BUSINESSAREAID) AS (SELECT BUSINESSAREAID FROM BUSINESSAREA WHERE BUSINESSAREANAME = @BUSINESSAREANAME),
t2 (STAFFID) AS (SELECT STAFFID FROM STAFF WHERE STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME),
t3 (ROLEID) AS (SELECT ROLEID FROM ROLE WHERE ROLENAME = @ROLENAME)

INSERT INTO BARS ([BUSINESSAREAID],[STAFFID],[ROLEID],[BARSSTARTDATE],[BARSENDDATE])    
VALUES ((SELECT t1.BUSINESSAREAID, t2.STAFFID, t3.ROLEID FROM t1,t2,t3), @BARSSTARTDATE, @BARSENDDATE)


END
GO
```

Comment: `insert into t1 (c1, c2...) select cx, literal... from ...`

Comment: Please add the error(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to include the values directly in the `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO [BARS]
(
    [BUSINESSAREAID]
  , [STAFFID]
  , [ROLEID]
  , [BARSSTARTDATE]
  , [BARSENDDATE]
)
       SELECT 
           [t1].[BUSINESSAREAID]
         , [t2].[STAFFID]
         , [t3].[ROLEID]
         , @BARSSTARTDATE
         , @BARSENDDATE
       FROM [t1]
          , [t2]
          , [t3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
insert into bars([BUSINESSAREAID],[STAFFID],[ROLEID],[BARSSTARTDATE][BARSENDDATE]) 
    SELECT t1.BUSINESSAREAID, t2.STAFFID, t3.ROLEID FROM t1,t2,t3, @BARSSTARTDATE, @BARSENDDATE
```

Comment: no it does not work. the error :the select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list.

Answer (score 0):

why not put all the values on a variable for example;

declare @val1 
set @val1 = (select top 1 businessareaid from t1)

declare @val2 
set @val1 = (select top 1 staffid from t2)

insert into bars (val1,val2)
select @val1 , @val2